# Providing sum of execution time of previous jenkins jobs to next job in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Need help in figuring out a way in which we can get sum of execution time for previous jobs to be provided as input for next job in jenkins pipeline.
Say, P is a pipeline with n number of jobs

> J1 -> J2 -> J3 -> J4
>
> > I want to provide J4  input of executionTime(J1 + J2 + J3)
> >     Can anyone help me to arive at solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I must make something like this I will use Jenkins API, JsonSlurper and TimeUnit. 
That's sample code for this case:

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

def convert(int millisToConvert) {
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisToConvert);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisToConvert) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisToConvert) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1);

    String format = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", Math.abs(hours), Math.abs(minutes), Math.abs(seconds));

    return format;
}

node {
    def time = 0;
    int n = parameter.toInteger()
    def m = n - 1;
    def list = [] 
    for(int x=m; x<=n; x++){
        job = ["curl", "-k", "-u", "<user>:<apitoken>", "https://host/jenkins/view/TOOLS/job/somejob/{$x}/api/json?tree=duration"].execute().text
        list.push( job )
    }

    println list
    list.each {
        print it
        def d = new JsonSlurper().parseText( it );
        def t = d.duration;
        time += t;   
    }

    def VARIABLE = convert(time)
    println "Your time is ${VARIABLE}" 
}
```

You can control how many build you need to sum, and where to start by `n` and `m` parameter. I use `convert` to get format like 00:03:46, but it depends of Your need.

Output:

```java
Started by user 3sky
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /app/jenkins/home/workspace/testing_job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
  [{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","duration":175052}, {"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","duration":51014}]
[Pipeline] echo
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","duration":175052}
[Pipeline] echo
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","duration":51014}
[Pipeline] echo
Your time is 00:03:46
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```